# Force yield return method to throw exception at time of calling

Tags: c#, exception, yield-return

I have a method I've inherited that returns an `IEnumerable<whatever>` and does so via the `yield return myWhatever` construct:

```
public IEnumberable<whatever> GetWhatevers() {
    while (true) {      
        // do calculations
        yield return myWhatever
    }
}
```

I uncovered a bug that causes this to loop infinitely if one of the class's collections is null, so I added a check and wrote a test:

```
public IEnumberable<whatever> GetWhatevers() {

    if (_dependentList == null || _dependentList.Count == 0) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to process without whatevers");
    }

    while (true) {      
        // do calculations
        yield return myWhatever
    }
}

void MyWhateverThrowsIOEOnEmptyList() {
    var sut = new MyThing(null);
    Assert.ThrowsException<InvalidOperationException>(() => {
        var results = sut.GetWhatevers();
    });
}
```

I realize now that this test fails because I never actually start iterating the results even though I call the method (due to the `yield` construct).

I can fix the test by doing this:

```
void MyWhateverThrowsIOEOnEmptyList() {
    var sut = new MyThing(null);
    Assert.ThrowsException<InvalidOperationException>(() => {
        var results = sut.GetWhatevers().ToList();
    });
}
```

... but I don't like it.  This means that whatever caller is calling this method, they won't know until the result is attempted to be accessed that there's an IOE hidden inside.  This resultant variable could travel to Timbucktu and back, all the while never knowing that it's a time bomb.

So now, any time I use this method, I have to remember that there's a possible exception lurking within.

This method is far too complicated for me to want to re-write using a traditional loop.  Is there a way I can force the exception to be thrown at "call time" instead of at "resolution time" so that I can know at the time of calling that there's an issue?

Comment: (this ugly little side effect doesn't seem worth the advantages of `yield`...)

Comment: You could put the `yield return` code in `private GetWhateversInternal()` and have the public `GetWhatevers()` do the check, then `return GetWhateversInternal();`.

Comment: There is only one useful thing to do with an iterator.  They'll iterate it, guaranteed.  Whether you use ToList() or foreach or call MoveNext() does not matter one bit, it is all the same.

Comment: @HansPassant - I hadn't realized this was an iterator per se (first time dealing with `yield`), but I think we're about to adopt a minor adjustment to our naming conventions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the iterator method from another:

```
public IEnumerable<Whatever> GetWhatevers(){
    if (_dependentList == null || _dependentList.Count == 0) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to process without whatevers");
    }

    return GetWhatevers_Impl();
}

private IEnumerable<Whatever> GetWhatevers_Impl(){
     while (true) {      
        // do calculations
        yield return myWhatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Herp-a-derpa, that'd be the key.  I'll give it to you because you answered first, but thanks to the others as well.